# Extracting Day of Week as an Integer with Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

This should be doable, but how can I extract the day of the week from a field containing data in date format with Netezza SQL?  I can write the following query:

SELECT date_part('day',a.report_dt) as report_dt
FROM table as a

but that gives me the day of the month.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 10):

The below queries give day numbers for any week,month,year for a particular date.

```
--Day of Week 
SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM report_dt) FROM table;
--Day of Month
SELECT DATE_PART('day', report_dt) FROM table;
--Day of Year
SELECT EXTRACT(doy FROM report_dt) FROM table;
```

Comment: +1 To add, week starts from Sunday. `1=Sunday, 7=Saturday`. That's unlike java where week starts from Monday.

Answer (score 2):

Netezza is just ANSI SQL, originally derived from PostgreSQL. I'd expect this to work.

```
select extract(dow from a.report_dt) as report_dt
from table as a
```

Returns values should range from 0 to 6; 0 is Sunday. You might expect that to be an integer, but in PostgreSQL at least, the returned value is a double-precision floating point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract directly the day name :

```
Select to_char(date, 'Day') as Day_Name From table;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Netezza SQL, SELECT EXTRACT(dow FROM report_dt) would return values 1 to 7. 1 is Sunday, 7 is Saturday.